# Set Up A Global Dashboard For A Specific User Group

Tags: users, dashboard-widgets

Is there a way to set the Dashboard up globally for a specific user group and lock it so that it can't be edited?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dashboard widgets are currently set on a per user basis. Brandon has said on the Google+ community that a site-wide and/or user group solution is planned but doesn't have en ETA.

https://plus.google.com/106689452282751248337/posts/CvZZa5DDGwb

https://plus.google.com/103717873128586100650/posts/gW9buKqF4LA

Comment: Did this find its way into craft yet? Looks pretty silly for new users having a dashboard with 12 create new entries boxes.... :/

Comment: @nexflo Not yet. If you're looking for more information, contact P&T directly at support@buildwithcraft.com

Answer (score 4):

I have developed a plugin to do this https://github.com/james1238/duplicateuserdashboard